# Python object in class return as tuple

Tags: python, class

I have following code

```py
class example:
    def __init__(self, df, name, location):
        self.df=df,
        self.name=name,
        self.location=location

s = example(df=df, name=config['unique_id'], location=config['source'])

s.df
```

which gives output:

```
(   name  amount
 0  john     100
 1   tom     400,)
```

Why does my dataframe return as a tuple?

Answer (score 2):

Because of commas at the end of lines within `__init__` - in Python this indicates tuples.

So it's equivalent to `self.df = (df,)`

Comment: Ha, for sure...it's been a long day!

Comment: Even after a decade with Python, from time to time I'm still falling into the same trap right after working with JSON:)

Answer (score 1):

Because you're returning : {arg1,arg2,arg3}
and you should do :

```
class example:
    def __init__(self, df, name, location):
        self.df = df
        self.name = name
        self.location = location
```

Comment: `returning : {arg1,arg2,arg3}` not literally returning, and not quite complaining about a set.